# ACS712 Module inaccurate reading in some devices

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, current

I'm currently trying to isolate what's the problem with a current sensor build I'm working on right now. I'm using a ACS712 that can handle 30A, I've used the code at

http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-current-measurements/acs712-arduino-ac-current-tutorial/

And so far for certain devices like pencil sharpeners, computers, chargers, and other household devices the amperage readout seems is "correct" there's some minor error due to the noise I assume.. There's like .10 amperage difference. But when I plug in a stereo amplifier the error sky rockets to 1 Amp to even 2 Amps and I'm not quite sure what's the problem, I've also tried multiple codes online and all of them reach the same conclusion.

Thanks,

Comment: how do you know that there is an error?

Comment: I use an amp meter to detect if the current matches, and the readout does not match therefore an error